# How to sort dictionary in numeric order?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have an output like the following dictionary.

```
dict = {"1":df1,"10":df2,"11":df11,"4":df4,'5':df5,"6":df6}
```

I want to rearrange the order of the dictionary by the numeric order of the keys as below.

```
dict = {1":df1,"4":df4,'5':df5,"6":df6,"10":df2,"11":df11}
```

I tried

```
OrderedDict(sorted(dict .items()))
```

However, this did not work.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: In general, it is better to use a variable name that doesn't "hide" the built-in functions, such as `dict`. If you name it `dict`, you won't be able to use the built-in function `dict` later in your code.

Comment: Is your dict meant to be immutable? If not, what should happen if you add a key/value pair, e.g `'7'/df56`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THe problem is that strings are sorted *lexicographically*. So that means that `'1' < '10' < '2'`. We can however solve that by making a mapping to `int`, like:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[0])))
```

this will yield a result that looks like:

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('1', df1), ('4', df4), ('5', df5), ('6', df6), ('10', df2), ('11', df11)])
```

Note that since [python-3.7](/questions/tagged/python-3.7), dictionaries use the insertion order, and hence there is no need to use an `OrderedDict`. As [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127309/how-to-sort-dictionary-in-numeric-order/57127319?noredirect=1#comment100771372_57127319) says, there is still a subtle difference since "*the order of the keys in an `OrderedDict` affect `equality`, but not in a dict.*".

> **Note**: please do *not* use `dict` as variable name, since this will override the reference to the `dict` class.

Comment: There's still a subtle difference between `dict` and `OrderedDict`: the order of the keys in an `OrderedDict` affect equality, but not in a `dict`.